# Image tag stripped out of a div in IE9

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

So in IE9 everything shows up pretty good on our site except for a callout in the right sidebar. The code is supposed to look like this

```
<div class="live-chat-wrap">
<center>
<div id='LP_DIV_1363616998497' style='width:125px;height:155px;'>
<img src="foo-image.jpg" />
</div>
</center>
</div>
```

but IE9 is stripping out the `img` tag. You can visit our [site (link)](http://www.nst.com) to see whats going on. There is a big empty spot above the magazine picture on the right. But only on IE9. In chrome it renders fine but in IE the image tag has been totally stripped out. Any ideas? I did have some CSS3 transitions applied to the picture but I've never seen them rip out HTML.

Thanks guys

Comment: The image tag is actually stripped out in Firefox as well from what I can tell, though I see an actual image above the magazine in both FF and IE9.  If this is different than you see, it could be some kind of caching issue.  I also suspect that the <div class="live-chat-wrap"> is somehow removing the tag, or something else is at play.

Comment: @Daniel well its being dynamically inserted through ASP (which is dumb but I cant change it) and the wrapping `div` is to style the whole dynamic element.

Comment: @Daniel I just checked another computer in the office and it isn't showing there either so it is definitely not a caching issue.

Comment: Are you running any third party browser addins that might be stripping the DOM of your markup?  Adblock and NoScript come to mind. NoScript is stripping it out of FF on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you on about? It's fine! I tested it on BrowserStack.com on Windows 7 in IE9. The image is NOT stripped out.